# Ask user permission to record audio, read phone state and foreground service?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm building an audio app and I have this in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

I notice in Kitkat, for example, my app works well. But it has no permission to microphone and telephone in Android 10 (also the app crashes, permission denial: startForeground requires android permission foreground_service).

So I add: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />` in manifest.

Now what should I do in mainactivity? I need to ask users permission to record audio, read phone state and foreground either?

I try this:

```
private final String [] permissions = {
        "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO",
        "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",
        "android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"
};

    int requestCode = 200;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode);
    }
```

Is it correct?

Comment: `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` is not a `dangerous` permission, so you do not need to request it at runtime. If your service is looking to record audio from that service, though, you will need [to declare your foreground service types](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types)

Comment: @CommonsWare I added `<service android:name="org.puredata.android.service.PdService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="microphone|phoneCall" />` is it correct? Do I need phoneCall too because of read_phone_state?

Comment: "is it correct?" -- it looks plausible, but you might ask the authors of this library. "Do I need phoneCall too because of read_phone_state?" -- I do not think so.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will request the user for permission. Once the user accepts no permission dialog is popped up.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                    requireContext(),
                    Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO
                )
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            ) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    (context as Activity?)!!,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO),
                    1
                )
            }
```

Comment: What about phone_state? Do I need permission too?

Comment: yes above Android 10 we need to request for user permission. replace RECORD_AUDIO from the above code.

Comment: What is `(context as Activity?)!!`?? And `requireContext()`? Doesn't exist. Same for `arrayOf`.